# Use of HTML page in WEB application

Tags: html, jsp, web-applications

When we are developing web application using jsp servlet or using Struts2 or Spring then we are basically using `HTML` or `JSP` page for displaying data to the user.

But we know that `JSP` and `HTML` both are  different concept. Even I also used `HTML` page sometimes in my project but I am getting confused why we are using `HTML` page instead of `JSP` page in web application?

Can someone explain why we are using `HTML` page in WEB application?

Comment: I'm going to assume you're serious. I'd rather assume that, because otherwise I don't know what you're after. It could be because the pages you're generating on the server don't have any special logic, and are just plain HTML?

Comment: Are you asking in terms of advantages of one over the other? Your question isn't clear.